# Resolve resource call before controller load with OcLazyLoad

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, oclazyload

I need to perform an http call to my webservice using a $resource provider.
I'd like to resolve first the data coming from the http call, then inject this result in the controller.
Thinking in terms of OcLazyLoad I just wrote this piece of code.
In my mind it should:

- First load service;
- Make the http call;
- When the promise is resolved, load the controller

  ```
  .state('app.user.customer.detail', {
  url: '/{id}',
  templateUrl: "assets/views/customerDetail.html",
  resolve: { loadMyService: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$injector', 
                  function($ocLazyLoad, $injector) {
          return $ocLazyLoad.load('assets/js/services/customer.js').then(
                      function() {                            
                          return $ocLazyLoad.load('assets/js/services/customerFirstService.js').then(function() {

                              var $serviceTest = $injector.get("CustomerFirstLoad");
                              $serviceTest.testLoad();

                              }).then(function(){
                                          return $ocLazyLoad.load(['assets/js/controllers/customerCtrl.js']);
                                });
                          });

                   }]}
  ```

This is the service

```
'use strict';

app.factory('CustomerFirstLoad', ['$q', '$timeout', function Customers($q, $timeout) {
    var svc = {};

    svc.testLoad = function(){
        var deferrer = $q.defer(); 

        $timeout(function(){
            console.log("response");
            deferrer.resolve("response");
        }, 3000);
      return deferrer.promise;
  };

return svc;
}]);
```

Some advices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
.state('app.user.customer.detail', {
url: '/{id}',
templateUrl: "assets/views/customerDetail.html",
resolve: { loadMyService: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$injector', 
                function($ocLazyLoad, $injector) {
        return $ocLazyLoad.load('assets/js/services/customer.js').then(
                    function() {                            
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load('assets/js/services/customerFirstService.js').then(function() {

                            var $serviceTest = $injector.get("CustomerFirstLoad");
                            return $serviceTest.testLoad(); // <-- CHANGED HERE

                            }).then(function(){
                                        return $ocLazyLoad.load(['assets/js/controllers/customerCtrl.js']);
                              });
                        });

                 }]}
```

You need to return the promise of `$serviceTest.testLoad()` becouse in this way `$ocLazyLoad` doesn't go on until `$serviceTest.testLoad()` finished.

Comment: you are simply the best!

Comment: How can we pass result of $serviceTest.testLoad()(if it is return something) to controller?

Comment: thanks a lot you just save me from a lot of troubles